# How to write the code in "function printOut(){} " in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with how to code this program in javascript. The javascript code should load a character from a box and a number (N) from another box. When you press a button, N rows prints each one of those with N characters (same characters that are loaded are printed). Before printing, check that it is only available a character in the box where characters are to be entered.

code in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="theText"></p>
<p id="theNumber"></p>
    a charachter: <input type="charachter" id="theChar">
    a number: <input type="number" id="theNbr">
    <button onclick="printOut()">print out!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in Javascript:

```
function printOut(){

var theText = document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML= 
document.getElementById("theChar").value;

var theNumber = document.getElementById("theNbr").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("theNumber").innerHTML= 
document.getElementById("theNbr").value;



var newText= theText;
var outPut; 

for(i = 0; i<theNumber; i++){
newText =newText + theText; 
}

newText = newText + "<br>";

for( i = 0; i< theNumber; i++){
outPut = outPut + newText;
}

document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML= outPut;
}
```

Comment: Show us your effort..

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you take a little time to take the [tour] and read the [ask] page. There are some rules in this site, to help for content quality and so that questions can be answered more easily. In your case, the site is not a free coding service, you should provide an attempt at solving your problem and ask somethink specific. Good luck!

Comment: You could alert("print out") with the values from #theChar and #theNbr. Look up how to get an element from the DOM in javascript and you will find plenty of examples. DOM is the source available on the page and javascript plays very nicely with it. As a side note, 'charachter' is spelled character. It is important in programming to use correct spelling and grammar. It is also important when interacting with others as it makes people more likely to aid you.

Comment: You could also have a read-only text field and have the Javascript set its value to the character and the number. That would then dynamically show on the page.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the suggestions and tips.

Comment: You don't have a `theText` element in your HTML. And so there will be no output, but an error. NB: It is good practice to indent your code properly, it will help you later to understand your own code.

Comment: Hi guys, I have added some code to the function and it should print out N rows each one of those with N characters. But it gives me an error called "undefined". Do you guys see where the problem is? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Now I have it and it gives the same error!

Comment: Do you know how to use the console to debug? I mean, there are several very basic errors which you should just look at using the console and fix them. For instance, the content of `theNumber` is overwritten in your code, so that `theNbr` no longer exists in your HTML and so the reference to it in the next line fails. We could go on like that and visit every little error, but you should really help yourself and use the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, even after the corrections you made after comments were made. Some of the more important:

- Don't use `innerHTML` on an `input` element. It makes no sense. To get its value, use `value`.
- Don't assign to `document.getElementById("theNumber").innerHTML`: it will *replace* any HTML you already had, and thus will *remove* the `theNbr` input. Any reference to it will fail with an error from now on.
- Initialise your variables before reading from them. `outPut` is never initialised and so `outPut + newText` will give undesired results.

Although your can do this with `for` loops, there is a nice string method in JavaScript with which you can repeat a character or even a longer string: [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).

Here is how it could work:

```js
function printOut(){
    var theNumber = document.getElementById("theNbr").value; // Don't use innerHTML
    var theChar = document.getElementById("theChar").value;
    var oneLine = theChar.repeat(theNumber) + "<br>";
    var output = oneLine.repeat(theNumber);
    document.getElementById("theText").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
a charachter: <input type="charachter" id="theChar">
a number: <input type="number" id="theNbr">
<button onclick="printOut()">print out!</button>
<p id="theText"></p>
```